# ImageView does not work in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have problem with drawwing in ImageView. When the line is drawn in onCreate() all OK, but when in draw qwe() it is not drawn. Because?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Bitmap myBitmap;
Canvas myCanvas;
ImageView myImageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
config();
}

public void config()
{
  myBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
myCanvas=new Canvas(myBitmap);
      myImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<200;j++)
            myBitmap.setPixel(i, j, 0xffffff00);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    Paint myPaint=new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(0xff000000);
    myCanvas.drawLine(10, 10, 190, 190, myPaint);

}

public void qwe(View v)
{   
     myImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Paint myPaint=new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(0xff000000);
    myCanvas.drawLine(30, 100, 100, 30, myPaint);
    myImageView.draw(myCanvas);
     myImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

}
```

}

Comment: are you getting any error ? post your logcat message

Comment: what's qwe? Do you have a button with the onClick property inside your layout?

Comment: Lolz! Why it seems to funny to me? 
myImageView.draw(myCanvas);
myImageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

You called .draw() method first and then you called "findViewById(..)" after that?

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`myImageView.draw(myCanvas)` draws the imageview over whatever there's on the canvas, including the line you drew previously.

Overall it's unclear what you want to achieve. After `config()` the imageview is already displaying whatever is on the canvas, so drawing the imageview to itself seems suspicious. The last `findViewById()` doesn't serve a purpose either.

Answer (score 0):

Use myImageView.invalidate() instead of myImageView.draw(myCanvas).